# Error in installing mysql on centos7 (No package mysql-community-server available)

Tags: mysql, centos

I tried to install `mysql` on `centos-7` for first time, and I did these steps

1. sudo yum localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el7-1.noarch.rpm
2. sudo yum install mysql-community-server

when I reach the `step two` I got this `error`

> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
> * base: mirrors.ges.net.pk
> * epel: mirror.hostnet.nl
> * extras: mirror.natro.com
> * updates: mirror.radoreservers.com
> No package mysql-community-server available.
> Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 1):

1: wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm

2: rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm

3: yum install -y mysql-community-server

Comment: error: mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm: not an rpm package (or package manifest):

Comment: wget https://repo.mysql.com/mysql80-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm